# check if element exists in state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How could I access to the element in state array for example

```
this.state = {
    items: [1,5,22,6],
}
```

here I'm trying to set up a class if the id exists in items state

```
{this.props.data.map((row)=> (
 <ul>
  <li key={row.id} className={row.id === this.state.items ? 'complete' : 'pending'}" >{row.name}</li>
</ul>

))}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the .includes() function for arrays:

```
{this.props.data.map((row)=> (
   <ul>
     <li key={row.id} className={this.state.items.includes(row.id) ? 'complete' : 'pending' }>{row.name}</li>
   </ul>
))}
```

Alternatively use .indexOf():

```
{this.props.data.map((row)=> (
   <ul>
     <li key={row.id} className={this.state.items.indexOf(row.id) !== -1 ? 'complete' : 'pending' }>{row.name}</li>
   </ul>
))}
```

Comment: Note that `.includes()` astonishingly isn't supported in IE.